# How to change the colors of HTML form elements displayed in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, html, css, uiwebview

I have an application that opens HTML pages in a UIWebView. The pages have a specific color theme, which is disrupted by form elements on the page (I have few "select" fields), which have their own color theme (white font, light gray background). CSS can't seem to force it to display in other colors.

Does anyone know how to fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `-webkit-appearance: none;` to disable the browser's default styling, then apply your own styles. [More info and examples at 37signals](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit).

Comment: That's it! Fixed the issue, thanks Nick! Learned something new today. :)

Comment: So did I - I vaguely remembered that something like that property existed, but I couldn't remember what it was called until I looked it up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!important` in your external CSS styles. It could be that the style sheets for UIWebView are inline and are overriding your external styles.

For example, `select { color:#000!important; }` should override any inline style text color (unless it is set to `!important` as well) on `<select>` elements.

Comment: Nope, tried that and it doesn't change a thing. And it's not my app specific, I just tested the URL in iPhone Safari, same thing happens.

Comment: @AragornSG - Can you post the CSS and HTML you're using?